# Banner with text and a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a custom banner to a view in my android project. I want to do something similar to what I am seeing in this iPhone app

[image]

So far I have this inside of a relative layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll1PostVideoPortrait"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Post Video"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Needless to say, it looks nasty
[image]

Any better ideas how to achieve the look from the iOS screenshot?

Comment: You could use an ActionBar. Or a Layout (I prefer RelativeLayouts, but a LinearLAyout will work) with two TextViews. The rest is just a matter of colors, font sizes and styles. Notice that TextViews are **clickable**, so you really don't need Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout..

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="60dp"
   android:background="#3f3f3f" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="cancel" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Post Video" />

</RelativeLayout>


Note:
For click events, you can set ClickListener on TextViews.
```

Hope this helps you....